# handling multiple components that can fold

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have this kind of problematic :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
    <item [content]="item.content" [title]="item.title" [open]="true" (toggleclicked)="/*triggered when a user wants to fold/unfold*/"></item>
</ng-container>
```

the [open] input is a boolean that indicate if my component should be "folded" or "expanded". Is there a simple way to manage multiple component like this in an ngFor ?

Is it a better practice if my  has an internal state and manage the fold/unfold by itself ?

Comment: I think I can understand what you want. Why not use [Bootstrap collapsible items](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) ?

Comment: I don't know much about bootstrap and I need also to be able to have controls like toggleAll()

Comment: It's amazingly simple and the `toggleAll()` function can be done by you in 3 lines using Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not quite clear if you have a component `item` to handle everything, with the code you provided, I'd say you should use the item itself to handle if it's open or not.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
    <item [content]="item.content" [title]="item.title" [open]="item.open" (click)="item.open = !item.open"></item>
</ng-container>
```

If you need to toggle open/closed everything, you can have a button linked to a function like this:

```
function toggleAll() {
     this.collapseAll = !this.collapseAll
     this.list.forEach(x => x.open = collapseAll)
}
```

If you have more relevant code that might affect the answer, edit you question and I will try to adjust the answer.